# How to install gnome extensions from gnome software?

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-software

[image]

clearlinux has integrated the gnome extension in gnome software itself.

Comment: Works the same in Ubuntu: also here, you should find extensions in Software, at least up to 19.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) (this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029306/480481)

Comment: @vanadium extensions are not shown in my gnome-software. any plugins that i need to install?

Comment: I cannot check in 20.04, still in 19.10. The software center there has been overhauled in 20.04 (it is now a SNAP) so it is possible that extensions currently do not show up there.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Software Center currently is a Snap. While it is designed to replace the old Software Center, it is currently malfunctioning. At some stage, only Snap packages would be shown. Gnome Shell extensions not being available may be another issue.

As a workaround until issues with the new Ubuntu Software in 20.04 are fixed, you may [install the Gnome Software application](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/04/15/ubuntu-software-no-application-found/). You can do so with the terminal command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Look for the icon labeled "Software" instead of "Ubuntu Software" to start this "classical" version.

Comment: Can't find Gnome extensions in `gnome-software`. ;( At least there are `apt search -n gnome-shell-extension` and the `gnome-extensions` command-line tool...

Comment: Me neither. It seems https://fedoramagazine.org/install-extensions-via-software-application/ is deprecated